# how to capture the properties tag from json file

Tags: linux, awk, json, jq

this is very short list of my json file:

```
  "slider-client" : {
    "properties_attributes" : { },
    "properties" : { }
  }
},
{
  "spark2-hive-site-override" : {
    "properties_attributes" : { },
    "properties" : {
      "hive.metastore.client.connect.retry.delay" : "5",
      "hive.server2.enable.doAs" : "false",
      "hive.server2.thrift.port" : "10016",
      "hive.server2.transport.mode" : "binary",
      "hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout" : "1800"
    }
  }
},
{
  "tez-env" : {
    "properties_attributes" : { },
    "properties" : {
      "heap_dump_location" : "/tmp",
      "content" : "\n# Tez specific configuration\nexport TEZ_CONF_DIR={{config_dir}}\n\n# Set HADOOP_HOME to point to a specific hadoop install directory\nexport HADOOP_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME:-{{hadoop_home}}}\n\n# The java implementation to use.\nexport JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}",
      "enable_heap_dump" : "false",
      "tez_user" : "tez"
    }
  }
},
```

how we can capture only the lines that start with:

```
"properties" : {
```

and ended with

```
 }
```

example of expected output

```
    "properties" : { }
    "properties" : {
      "hive.metastore.client.connect.retry.delay" : "5",
      "hive.server2.enable.doAs" : "false",
      "hive.server2.thrift.port" : "10016",
      "hive.server2.transport.mode" : "binary",
      "hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout" : "1800"
    }

    "properties" : {
      "heap_dump_location" : "/tmp",
      "content" : "\n# Tez specific configuration\nexport TEZ_CONF_DIR={{config_dir}}\n\n# Set HADOOP_HOME to point to a specific hadoop install directory\nexport HADOOP_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME:-{{hadoop_home}}}\n\n# The java implementation to use.\nexport JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}",
      "enable_heap_dump" : "false",
      "tez_user" : "tez"
    }
```

what I did until now is this syntax , is it the best approach ?

```
 awk '/"properties" : {/,/^[[:blank:]]*}$/'  file.json
```

Comment: Your JSON excerpt is not valid JSON, important parts are missing. The simplest way to do what you want is use to use `jq`, but without knowing the exact JSON format, we can't make a ready-to-use answer. Have you tried reading the `jq` man page, and attempting it yourself?

Comment: yes I read the jq but after few tests I cant to find the right way

Comment: maybe awk that runs on the file

Comment: There are plenty of questions here about parsing a JSON file and sensible answers will always be based on a JSON parser, not on `sed`/`awk`. Unless of course you have full control on the JSON output and thus can avoid all kind of side-effects, which you didn't state in your question.

Answer (score 1):

To be a valid JSON your input should be considered as an array of objects.

***jq*** solution:

```
jq '.[] | to_entries[] | .value | if has("properties") then {"properties": .properties} else empty end' yourfile
```

The output (corrected):

```
{
  "properties": {}
}
{
  "properties": {
    "hive.metastore.client.connect.retry.delay": "5",
    "hive.server2.enable.doAs": "false",
    "hive.server2.thrift.port": "10016",
    "hive.server2.transport.mode": "binary",
    "hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout": "1800"
  }
}
{
  "properties": {
    "heap_dump_location": "/tmp",
    "content": "\n# Tez specific configuration\nexport TEZ_CONF_DIR={{config_dir}}\n\n# Set HADOOP_HOME to point to a specific hadoop install directory\nexport HADOOP_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME:-{{hadoop_home}}}\n\n# The java implementation to use.\nexport JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}",
    "enable_heap_dump": "false",
    "tez_user": "tez"
  }
}
```

Comment: I run it but we get this "jq: error: Cannot check whether string has a string key"

Comment: @jango, I repeat (as I wrote it in my answer): **To be a valid JSON your input should be considered as an array of objects**

Comment: sorry but seems my json not include array of objects so what we can do with this?

Comment: @jango, *what we can do*? that means that your input is not a valid json or not a json at all. Do restructure your input to make it valid json, or don't call it *json*

Comment: what you think about this - awk '/"properties" : {/,/^[[:blank:]]*}$/'  file.json

Comment: @jango: Please, as has been mentioned multiple times [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/386350/edit) your question and include a valid and representative example. Also read and follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instructions

Comment: see my update in the question , I write my solution but not sure that this is the right syntax

Comment: what you think about ny solution ?

Comment: @Thor do you have opinion about my solution ?

Comment: @jango: You do not listen, so no opinion

Comment: but I give here awk solution , why awk not good for this?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  any opinion about my solution ?

Answer (score -1):

to capture the properties until "}" we can do:

```
awk '/"properties" : {/,/^[[:blank:]]*}$/'  file.json
```

Comment: I will happy to get any comments ?

Comment: awk/sed are not the right tools to work with json at all

Comment: yes but this awk do the job very well

Comment: it can be called an arbitrary happy case, but not robust solution. It should not be advised to other people/community

Comment: Does it handle well properties with value `{ }`?